# How to get the intersection and symmetric difference of 2 objects in seperate arrays with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object

It seems weird that this isn't an duplicate, but I cant find what I want so here is what I want:

I have 2 arrays. array 1 is new data I reveived from an API. array 2 is old data I recieved from my database.

I want to filter out the items from array 1 that are equal to the items in array 2 (by id), and collect them in my alreadyExist array. Also I want to filter out the items from array 1 that do not exist in object 2 (new items). And the items from object 2 that do not exist in object 1 (removed items). I collect these all in seperate arrays. So a alreadyExist, new and removed array.

Long short, I want the intersection and symmetric difference of 2 objects in seperate arrays in the fastest way possible because I use alot of data.

My api can give me a array of 200.000+ objects with each 65 fields in it. My database can give me a 200.000+ objects with each 25 fields.

I have the intersection.

This is my code:

```
let itemAlreadyExistArray = [];
// Final object its fields.
let finalObject = {
    id: null, 
    field2: null, 
    field3: null, 
    field4: null, 
    objectName: null
    password: null
}

// Get each item in array1.
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

    // Get each item in array2.
    for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {

        // Check if already exists (intersection part)
        if (array1[i].id == array2[j].id) {

            finalObject.id = array1[i].id;
            finalObject.field2 = array1[i].id;
            finalObject.field3 = array1[i].id;
            finalObject.field4 = array1[i].id;
            finalObject.objectName = array1[i].id;
            finalObject.password= array2[j].id;   // From another array.

            // Add item.
            itemAlreadyExistArray.push(finalObject);

            // Better for speed performance.
            break;
        }

        // If there is no id matching then means its either new or removed.
        if (j == (array2- 1)) {
            // ?????
        }
    }
}
```

This is my array data, its fake but lookd the same as mine:

```
// From DB
array1 [
    object1 {
        id: "982AD74234", 
        field2: null, 
        field3: "85414090", 
        field4: "AWHDAWDAdadsd", 
        password: myFirstPassword
    },

    object2 {
        id: "98D3354daw4", 
        field2: null, 
        field3: "85414090", 
        field4: "AWHDAWDAdadsd", 
        password: mySecondPassword
    }
]

//From API
array2 [
    object1 {
        id: "533da657sd68", 
        field2: null, 
        field3: "85414090", 
        field4: "AWHDAWDAdadsd", 
        objectName: "some Object 1"
    },

    object2 {
        id: "5345hta346", 
        field2: null, 
        field3: "85414090", 
        field4: "AWHDAWDAdadsd", 
        objectName: "some Object 2"
    },

    object3 { // Equal to array1-object 1
        id: "982AD74234", 
        field2: null, 
        field3: "85414090", 
        field4: "AWHDAWDAdadsd", 
        objectName: "some Object 3"
    },

    object4 {
        id: "9827js4233544", 
        field2: null, 
        field3: "85414090", 
        field4: "AWHDAWDAdadsd", 
        objectName: "some Object 4"
    }
]
```

**Also** I have to change the data inside the objects of array1 and array2 and merge some fields together.

So with the example above I need to be able to have this array with objects when the object id's match (intersection):
**I merged the password I got from my database with the objectName I got from my API into one object with some other standard data.**

**Also note: ID's** can have **numbers and letters!**

```
alreadyExists [
    object3 { // Equal to array1-object1
        id: "982AD74234", 
        field2: null, 
        field3: "85414090", 
        field4: "AWHDAWDAdadsd", 
        objectName: "some Object 3"
        password: myFirstPassword     //Merged from array1-object1
    }
]
```

When I need to check if an object is new or removed I use some standard object data. So then it does not need to be changed/merged.

Comment: show us your input data and also your expected output.

Comment: it would help to get an example of what your 2 objects look like

Comment: use set intersection - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: Do your objects in the array really have unique keys, e.g. `array1[0].object3.id` but otherwise always have the same structured content?!

Comment: Im not so sure what you mean. But I think its not always the same. At least not the content of array1 and array2. Array1 is from an api, it has alot of products from a company inside it. Array2 is from my database, it has the same products but the api products have changes to the products in the database (e.g. price changes). Also some products can be expired and some can be new. Products are objects in this case. EDIT: I think I understand now, the objects always have the same keys, yes.

Comment: @Allart the problem is your notation e.g. `object3  = { ... }` - it's not legal syntax, so it's unclear whether you mean `{ object3: { ... } }`, or just using it as a pseudo-placeholder.

Comment: @Alnitak I see, sorry I edit it. My actual data isn't like that.

Comment: you've massively changed the question, since now you're also wanting to _merge_ in new keys ("password: myFirstPassword     //Merged from array1-object1").    I was writing an answer, but now I'm outta here...

Comment: Lol, sorry bro. Mistakes happen I guess. Next time ill think about asking a better question if I can.

Comment: @Allart I'm awaking a sleepy thread, but I just noticed the merge requirement for common objects. I've updated my response accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I have a dirty hands approach rather than a JavaScript-cool-predefined-prototype-usage one, but you can do it in roughly 4 array crosses, regardless the length.

```js
const array1 = [{ id: 1 },{ id: 2 },{ id: 3 },{ id: 4 },{ id: 5 }];
const array2 = [{ id: 1 },{ id: 4 },{ id: 7 },{ id: 8 },{ id: 5 }];

const array1Dic = {}; // Mapping of id - object having that id
const commonDic = {}; // Mapping of id - object (making note of the common elements)

let array1Different = [];
const array2Different = [];
let common = [];

// Populate first dictionary - one iteration
array1.forEach(item => array1Dic[item.id] = item);

// Populate array2Different and commonDic - one iteration (NO OBJECT MERGE)
array2.forEach(item => !!array1Dic[item.id] ? (commonDic[item.id] = item) : (array2Different.push(item)));

// OR if you need merged common objects
// array2.forEach(item => !!array1Dic[item.id] ? (commonDic[item.id] = { ...item, ...array1Dic[item.id] }) : (array2Different.push(item)));

// Get array1Different using commonDic - one iteration
array1Different = array1.filter(item => !commonDic[item.id]);
common = Object.values(commonDic);

console.log(array1Different);
console.log(array2Different);
console.log(common);
```

**Explanation**:

Turning arrays into dictionaries (or dictionary-like objects) can insanely improve performance because there's no more array search for elements, but rather IDs for O(1) search.

I have turned one of the arrays into a dictionary, then iterated through the second one while constantly checking if the current element is in the above dictionary.

If yes, then it's a common element.
If no, then it's distinct and belongs to the second array.

Then, I have iterated through the first one again while checking elements with the `common` dictionary and `filter`-ed out the ones that are common, thus getting the distinct elements belonging to first array.

Common elements are stored in the `common` dictionary.

**Edit**: For object merge you can use the Spread operator to combine the properties of both objects. Check the code above for an example.

Comment: these days you should really use a `Set` or `Map` instead of a plain object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let prev_data = [
  {
    id : 1,
    title: 'prev title 1'
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    title: 'prev title 2'
  },
  {
    id : 3,
    title: 'prev title 3'
  },
]

let current_data = [
  {
    id : 1,
    title: 'prev title 1 changed'
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    title: 'prev title 2'
  },
  {
    id : 3,
    title: 'new title 3'
  },
]

// whole of object comparison.
let difference = current_data.filter(i=>!prev_data.some(p=>JSON.stringify(p)===JSON.stringify(i)));

let intersection = current_data.filter(i=>prev_data.some(p=>JSON.stringify(p)===JSON.stringify(i)));

console.log(difference);
console.log(intersection);

// limited attributes comparison if there is too many attr:
let differ = current_data.filter(i=>!prev_data.some(p=>p.id===i.id && p.title===i.title));

console.log(differ);
```

Comment: Also you can do both in one traverse using ```Array.reduce``` or ...

Comment: Sorry i changed my question a bit. Tnx for helping already

Comment: @Allart I wrote the answer general. It will work on any array of objects.

Comment: Im trying it, but my laptop is busy with it for 5 min now. I see nothing yet. I have alot of data I need to check. Both array's can have more then 200.000 objects with each 65 fields. I get array1 from an api and array2 from an db. I need to update the db with the data from the api and database together.

Comment: I did - using `JSON.stringify` is a foul idea.  It will fail on any object that is not serializable, and it's expensive, too.

Comment: @Allart if your data is too big you must check only limited attributes instead whole of object.

Comment: @cybercoder True but if I want to do that I have to do that in Javascript (which takes time aswell). The API is not able to give me less fields, for as far as I know atleast.

Comment: @Allert i'll update answer for limited attribute just a bit.

Comment: @Alnitak Why you think i don't know that? The question was not for huge data, at first.